# I can't implement the transfer function that calls the A contract through the B contract

Tags: solidity, transfer, erc20

I want to call the function of contract A in my contract B. I call the `balanceOf` function to display the balance normally, but when I call the `transfer` function, it does display
Note: The called function should be payable if you send value and the value you send should be less than your current balance. I can't even add payable. Can anyone help?

my A contract

```
function transfer(address _to, uint256 _value)
        external
        payable
        returns (bool success)
    {function transfer(address _to, uint256 _value)
        external
        payable
        returns (bool success)
    {
        require(balancesOf[msg.sender] >= _value);
        require(_to != address(0));
        require(balancesOf[_to] + _value > balancesOf[_to]);
        balancesOf[msg.sender] -= _value;
        balancesOf[_to] += _value;
        return true;
    }
```

my B contract

```
interface X {
    function balanceOf(address _owner) external view returns (uint256 balance);
    function transfer(address _to, uint256 _value)external payable returns (bool success);
}

contract A {
    X public token;
    
    constructor(address payable _address){
        token = X(_address);

    }
    
    function GetbalanceOf(address _owner) external view returns (uint balance) {
        return token.balanceOf(_owner);
    }
    function buy(address xx) external  {
         token.transfer(xx,100);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems like your not using any msg.value inside the transfer function of contract A henceforth u don't need the function to be payable. Also it might be because there is already a transfer function built in for sending ether.

You should change your transfer name to something else because its conflicting with the already built in transfer function of solidity.